# How to use a observer instead of Subjects for event messages in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, event-handling

I am using TypeScript and across my project I use [rxjs/Subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) for event messages.

Here is an example:

```js
class Downloader {

    const done = new Subject();

    download(): Promise<void> {
        return downloadSomeFile(...)
            .then(() => {
               done.next();
            });
    }
}
```

And somewhere else in my project I simply subscribe to it:

```
done.subscribe(() => { /* do something fancy */ });
```

This is technically possible but I have read that this is not in the design idea of `rxjs` and instead to use directly [Observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable). Why is that and how would my code snippet look like with the proper implementation?

Comment: In the function where this is being called are you returning the promise of DownloadsomeFile() or the done.AsObservable().

How will some where else in the project get access to 'done'?

Comment: I have a download manager class, and `done` is a member of it. Then a few consumers across my app can subscribe to `Subject`

Comment: is there a reason they are subscribing to done and not  'download()' promise, also done in your question is a private variable

Comment: Yes, because I have 1 caller and many other places which affects this. Only one can call `download()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member should only be able to subscribe to this as an observable and should not be  able to trigger `next` from outside.
Knowing multiple `subscription` would occur at a time, `subject` is the better choice.

```
class Downloader {
        
            private _done = new Subject(); // for triggering next

            public done = _done.asObservable(); // for subscribers as Observable
        
            public  download(): Promise<void> {
                return downloadSomeFile(...)
                    .then(() => {
                       this._done.next();
                    });
            }
        }
```